# massping command - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that gets 5 random people from a server and mentions them. What I have so far is this:

```
@bot.command()
async def massping(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    user = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    user2 = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    user3 = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    user4 = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)
    user5 = choice(ctx.message.channel.guild.members)

    message = await ctx.send(f'{user.mention}{user2.mention}{user3.mention}{user4.mention}{user5.mention}')
    await message.delete()
```

The problem with this is that sometime it pings the same person twice. Is there any way around this so I can ensure it always pings 5 different people?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) returns a list of Member objects, you can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to return unique elements from the list.

```
async def ping(ctx, num: int):
    members = [m.mention for m in ctx.guild.members]
    rand = random.sample(members, num)
    await ctx.send("\n".join(rand))
```

Comment: Is there a reason that this only works in some servers? In some servers this command does not work for my bot- getting this error "Command raised an exception: ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative". And no, I'm not mentioning more users than the server member count.